# Limits to infinity conjecture

Tags: calculus, limits

Let: $g: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ , $h: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Where g,h,f are functions. For the following conjectures, if they are true, prove it, if not, find a counterexample.

1) If $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty }  \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exists and $0 < \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty }  \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}< \infty $ then $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty }  \frac{g(x)}{f(x)}$ exists and $0 < \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty }  \frac{g(x)}{f(x)}< \infty $

2) If $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty }  \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exists and $0 < \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty }  \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}< \infty $ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty }  \frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$ exists and $0 < \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty }  \frac{g(x)}{h(x)}< \infty $ then:

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty }  \frac{f(x)}{h(x)}$ exists and $0 < \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty }  \frac{f(x)}{h(x)}< \infty $

I don´t think that the conjectures are true, but it is very difficult to find a counterexample. Any help or hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Both of your conjectures are true.

(1) There is a basic theorem about nested limits. It says the following: When  one has $\lim_{x\to\xi} a(x)=\alpha$ ($\xi=\infty$ is allowed here), and the function $p(\cdot)$ is continuous at $\alpha$, then
$$\lim_{x\to\xi} p\bigl(a(x)\bigr) =p(\alpha)\ .$$
Applying this principle to $a(x):={f(x)\over g(x)}$, $\>\lim_{x\to\xi} a(x)=\alpha\in{\mathbb R}^*$ and $p(y):={1\over y}$ gives
$$\lim_{x\to\xi} {g(x)\over f(x)}=\lim_{x\to\xi} p\bigl(a(x)\bigr)=p(\alpha)={1\over\alpha}\in{\mathbb R}^*\ .$$
(2) This is even simpler and follows immediately from the product rule for limits: When $g(x)h(x)\ne0$ in a (punctured) neighborhood of $\xi$ then under the stated assumptions 
$$\lim_{x\to\xi}{f(x)\over h(x)}=\lim_{x\to\xi}\left({f(x)\over g(x)}\cdot {g(x)\over h(x)}\right)
=\lim_{x\to\xi}{f(x)\over g(x)}\lim_{x\to\xi}{g(x)\over h(x)}=\alpha\>\beta\notin\{0,\infty\}\ .$$

Comment: So then fist conjecture is true, right ?? It seems that the second conjecture is not true ... If that is the case, can you please tell me an example where it is not true ??

Comment: @user132226: See my edit.